# Rails remote form, removing data-remote still fires remote

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form, and I want the first time to fire remote so I can generate a preview.  The second time I want to fire non-remote, a regular rails route.  So the first time, on clicking the button I do:

```
$("#case-form").attr("data-remote", "true")
$("#case-form").attr("action", "/cases/" + $(".preview")
```

If the user approves the preview, I want to remove the remote and do a full submission:

```
$("#case-form").removeAttr("data-remote")
$("#case-form").attr("action", "/cases")
```

However, the form still fires as remote, here's the log:

```
Processing by CasesController#create as JS
```

The browser inspector confirms that the form does in fact no longer have the data-remote attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: try to use [.removeData()](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/)

Comment: How's your route defined?